# Approximate transfer function expression of this circuit

Tags: transfer-function

I have a generic circuit like that one in the first photo: 4 impedences, and an alternating voltage generator; I want to calculate its transfer function (the output voltage divided by the input voltage).
Now, if I use the mesh or nodal analysis I get the result in the first photo (I'm sure it's correct). But in some cases I know I can multiply the transfer functions of the separeted two circuits shown in the second photo. I'm wondering why and in which cases?

I think that this approximation si valid if Z_3 is much less than Z_2 and Z_4, as you can see in my calculus. 
But is this the only case in which I can approximate the transfer function of a circuit like that one?

What do you think about it?

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to be answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can either use nodal analysis as you did or else take it in steps, as you suggest. Let's do the nodal analysis first, just to demonstrate how the result you provided is achieved. The bottom node in your schematic will be treated as a common, and is assigned \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ arbitrarily. Now working left to right, I'm labeling your voltage nodes on the top side as \$V_1\$ (input), \$V_2\$, and \$V_3\$ (output):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_2}{Z_1}+\frac{V_2}{Z_2}+\frac{V_2}{Z_3}&=\frac{V_1}{Z_1}+\frac{V_3}{Z_2}\\\\
\frac{V_3}{Z_2}+\frac{V_3}{Z_4}&=\frac{V_2}{Z_2}
\end{align*}$$

Since \$V_1\$ is a provided input, the above solves out as:

$$\begin{align*}
V_2&=V_1\cdot\frac{Z_3\cdot\left(Z_2+Z_4\right)}{Z_1\cdot Z_2 + Z_1\cdot Z_3 + Z_1\cdot Z_4 + Z_2\cdot Z_3 + Z_3\cdot Z_4}\\\\
V_3&=V_1\cdot\frac{Z_3\cdot Z_4}{Z_1\cdot Z_2 + Z_1\cdot Z_3 + Z_1\cdot Z_4 + Z_2\cdot Z_3 + Z_3\cdot Z_4}
\end{align*}$$

So I get your transfer function:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_3}{V_1}&=\frac{Z_3\cdot Z_4}{Z_1\cdot Z_2 + Z_1\cdot Z_3 + Z_1\cdot Z_4 + Z_2\cdot Z_3 + Z_3\cdot Z_4}
\end{align*}$$

Check!

---

Now, let's approach this in steps. Here, you find that you can replace \$V_1\$, \$Z_1\$, and \$Z_3\$ with its Theveinin equivalent. And then replace that circuit with yet another. So, here are the steps laid out in schematic form:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAppWt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice here that I've included something you've missed: \$Z_{TH}\$. So you have \$Z_{TH}=\frac{Z_1\cdot Z_3}{Z_1+Z_3}\$ and \$V_{TH}=V_1\cdot\frac{Z_3}{Z_1+Z_3}\$ and therefore the result is:

$$\begin{align*}
V_3&=V_{TH}\cdot\frac{Z_4}{Z_4+Z_2+Z_{TH}}\\\\
&=V_1\cdot\frac{Z_3}{Z_1+Z_3}\cdot\frac{Z_4}{Z_4+Z_2+\frac{Z_1\cdot Z_3}{Z_1+Z_3}}\\\\
&=V_1\cdot\frac{Z_3\cdot Z_4}{\left(Z_1+Z_3\right)\cdot\left(Z_4+Z_2\right)+Z_1\cdot Z_3}
\end{align*}$$

Or,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_3}{V_1}&=\frac{Z_3\cdot Z_4}{\left(Z_1+Z_3\right)\cdot\left(Z_4+Z_2\right)+Z_1\cdot Z_3}
\end{align*}$$

Which is the same result as before.

I just wanted to make sure that you didn't miss the \$Z_{TH}\$ from the first Thevenin conversion in your work. You need to include it in order to get to the same place.

Comment: Ok. Using Thevenin it's better. So, if z1*z3/(z1+z3) is negligible compared to (z2 + z4), then I can approximate the transfer function as the product of the transfers functions of the two separated circuits, right?

Comment: @PietroMeloni yes, that would seem correct.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to study a circuit and see how it could reduce to a simpler form when neglecting some of its element values, its is important to express the transfer function in a *low-entropy* form, a term forged by Dr. Middlebrook when teaching his extra-element theorem or EET (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem). A *low-entropy* form, is an expression in which you see how elements interact with each other, for instance trough series-parallel arrangements. You can also see a leading term which tells you if there is gain or attenuation at a certain frequency point (0 or infinity for instance). So in your example I can show for the sake of illustration how the EET can get you to a simple expression without using node analysis at all. First, select what is your extra element, the one without which all is simplified. I will work with resistances \$R\$ rather than \$Z\$ and will pick \$R_3\$ as my element. I have the choice to make it an infinite- or zero-valued element to determine my *reference* transfer function. I choose to make it an infinite value and I thus re-draw the circuit without \$R_3\$ to compute the reference transfer function \$H_{ref}\$. By looking at the below sketch, you immediately see that it is

\$H_{ref}=\frac{R_4}{R_4+R_2+R_1}\$

[image]

Then, I need to determine the resistance \$R_d\$ when the excitation voltage \$V_{in}\$ is reduced to 0 V (replace the source by a short circuit). When running this simple exercise, I obtain

\$R_d=R_1||(R_2+R_4)\$

The final step is obtained when I determine the resistance \$R_n\$ seen from \$R_3\$'s terminals when the response is nulled (\$V_{out}=0\;V\$) and the excitation is back in place. If I do this simple exercise - designated as a null double injection or NDI - I can see that \$R_n=0\;\Omega\$ since I have 0 V across the current test generator. What is even cooler is that I can use SPICE to check all these intermediate steps and verify (and correct) my results.

[image]

I'm done and can apply the EET expression which is

\$H=H_{ref}\frac{1+\frac{R_n}{R_3}}{1+\frac{R_d}{R_3}}=\frac{R_4}{R_4+R_2+R_1}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{R_1||(R_2+R_4)}{R_3})}\$

With the series-parallel arrangement, you can see the impact of each element and check how neglecting its value could impact the transfer function. The below Mathcad file verifies all these results

[image]

Of course, the EET is a kind of an overkill here -"only way to feel the noise..." : ), but it shows the basic principle of the Fast Analytical Circuits Techniques or FACTs (see http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf)

The Thévenin approach kindly sugested by jonk is already a first step towards FACTs because it breaks and simplifies the circuit, illustrating the "divide and conquer" theory at work with FACTs.